# Auto generate email when customer place the order?

Tags: magento-1.9

When i place the order then mail is not generate. My admin panel show:-

```
Order # 100000091 (the order confirmation email was sent)
```

**Order** and **Order Comments** setting in the `System->Configuration->Sale` Emails are Enabled **Yes**.
But i am not receiving the mail to my gmail account.

Comment: is cron jobs are working ? did you set up mail server in server ?

Answer (score 0):

Confirm crons are running for the site, also check the core_email_queue table and see if the email is sat there waiting to be sent.

Comment: DanCarlyon How i check crons are running for the site.. Because i check crons, but its not find out.

Comment: if you ssh into the server and the run the command `crontab -l` you should have one pointing to your htdocs/cron.php

Comment: cant we check that from dashboard...

Comment: If you install [Aoe Scheduler](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler) then you will have a page in the admin where you can view the cron schedule, other than that you have to ssh into the server

Comment: I have done the setting of this path:-system > configuration > system > ‘Cron (Scheduled Tasks)’ tab.  But its not working. Please give the suggestion what should i do......